# how to convert multiple object into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

can someone please help me with some code, i have two arrays one with product_ id and another one with product details i've managed to search from product_id array and display the details from product details. what i want to do is id more the one item is found it should return as a single array, please view my code and see what i am talking about. if someone can help me combined the result to an array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9yRa.jpg)

```js
var product_id = [{
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "203751",

  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "198999",

  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "199291",

  },

  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "256156",

  }
];

var product_details = [{
    "id": "219",
    "product_id": "198999",
    "sku": "20148089",
    "prod_name": "Chocolate Mousse 1L",

    "price": "39.99"
  },
  {
    "id": "220",
    "product_id": "199291",
    "sku": "20008307",
    "prod_name": "Medium Carrots 500g",

    "price": "9.99"
  },
  {
    "id": "221",
    "product_id": "2047590",
    "sku": "6009207908908",
    "prod_name": "Fresh Spicy Lentil & Vegetable Soup 600g",
    "price": "39.59"
  },
  {
    "id": "222",
    "product_id": "1990150",
    "sku": "6009182131643",
    "prod_name": "Bulk Gouda Cheese 900g",
    "price": "77.62"
  },
  {
    "id": "249",
    "product_id": "2000510",
    "sku": "6009195203320",
    "prod_name": "Salted Butter 500g",
    "price": "76.95"
  }

]
let e;
product_id.forEach(prod => {
  if (prod) {
    product_details.forEach(detail => {
      if (detail && detail.product_id === prod.product_id) {
        console.log(detail);
        e = detail;
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the motivation for doing this, given that you can easily access either array already using the `product_id` as a key?

Answer (score 0):

`e` should be an array, and when you find a match, then you should `push` to that array:

```js
var product_id=[{order_id:"281774",product_id:"203751"},{order_id:"281774",product_id:"198999"},{order_id:"281774",product_id:"199291"},{order_id:"281774",product_id:"256156"}],product_details=[{id:"219",product_id:"198999",sku:"20148089",prod_name:"Chocolate Mousse 1L",price:"39.99"},{id:"220",product_id:"199291",sku:"20008307",prod_name:"Medium Carrots 500g",price:"9.99"},{id:"221",product_id:"2047590",sku:"6009207908908",prod_name:"Fresh Spicy Lentil & Vegetable Soup 600g",price:"39.59"},{id:"222",product_id:"1990150",sku:"6009182131643",prod_name:"Bulk Gouda Cheese 900g",price:"77.62"},{id:"249",product_id:"2000510",sku:"6009195203320",prod_name:"Salted Butter 500g",price:"76.95"}];

let e = [];
product_id.forEach(prod => {
  product_details.forEach(detail => {
    if (detail.product_id === prod.product_id) {
      e.push(detail);
    }
  })
});

console.log(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `e` an array and push it, but you want to use **declarative methods** to make a new array because of two reasons:

- It's **easier to understand** beacuse the underlying logic is abstracted with the functions like `map()`, `reduce()`, `filter()`, etc.
- Mutating a variable might be not allowed in some cases like when you have to pass down a callback function to execute asynchronous operations.

You can use [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) and [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) to make a new array based on the original one like this:

```js
let product_id = [{ "order_id": "281774", "product_id": "203751" }, { "order_id": "281774", "product_id": "198999" }, { "order_id": "281774", "product_id": "199291" }, { "order_id": "281774", "product_id": "256156" }];
let product_details = [{ "id": "219", "product_id": "198999", "sku": "20148089", "prod_name": "Chocolate Mousse 1L", "price": "39.99" }, { "id": "220", "product_id": "199291", "sku": "20008307", "prod_name": "Medium Carrots 500g", "price": "9.99" }, { "id": "221", "product_id": "2047590", "sku": "6009207908908", "prod_name": "Fresh Spicy Lentil & Vegetable Soup 600g", "price": "39.59" }, { "id": "222", "product_id": "1990150", "sku": "6009182131643", "prod_name": "Bulk Gouda Cheese 900g", "price": "77.62" }, { "id": "249", "product_id": "2000510", "sku": "6009195203320", "prod_name": "Salted Butter 500g", "price": "76.95" }]

let product_id_only = product_id.map(id => id.product_id);
let result = product_details.filter(detail => product_id_only.includes(detail.product_id));
console.log(result);
```

Code explanation:

`product_id_only` is defined by the `map()` function, which makes a new array based on the return values of the callback provided, given every element in the array as parameter. Because the callback gets parameter `id` and returns `id.product_id`, the new array only consists of the `product_id` strings.

The `result` is calculated with the `filter()` function, which passes each element of the array and gets a boolean value as a return value. In this case, the `product_id_only.includes(detail.product_id)` is the return value, which is true when `detail`'s `product_id` is included in the previously made array with `map()`.

I hope it helps!